# Html 5 pushsate vs history.js vs HTML5-History-API

Tags: jquery, html, history.js, html5-history

I am planning to use html5 pushstate like described on this page

http://html5doctor.com/history-api/

but it supports only modern browsers. I searched on Google and found that there is another alternate which is history.js which supports more browsers.

I found two github links:

https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API

and

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

which one is correct.

Also, do i need to use it in conjunction with history api mentioned here http://html5doctor.com/history-api/ by checking browser version ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score -1):

I run into the same problem for IE and Android.
I found a very useful explanation of History API at:

http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#history

It says you can use Modernizr to detect browser compatibility:

```
if (Modernizr.history) {
  // history management works!
} else {
  // no history support :(
  // fall back to a scripted solution like History.js
}
```

or just detect if available:

```
function supports_history_api() {
  return !!(window.history && history.pushState);
}
```